# How get custom Table Data in phtml file without creating Model file. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.6

**I created custom table in my database through phpmyadmin, now I want display top1 record from that table on home page, and top2,top3 records need to display in product details page.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get your custom table data by following way

**Method - 1:** By using **Factory Method**

```
<?php

protected $_connection;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    .....
) {
    $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection();
}

public function getTableData()
{
    $myTable = $this->_connection->getTableName('table_name');
    $sql     = $this->_connection->select()->from(
         ["tn" => $myTable]
    ); 
    $result  = $this->_connection->fetchAll($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

Then you can get your custom table data in phtml file

```
$myTableData = $this->getTableData();

print_r($myTableData);
```

**Method - 2:** By using **objectManager**

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('your_table'); //gives table name

//Select Data from table
$sql = $connection->select()->from(
         ["tn" => $tableName]
    );
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick update, In which file i need to keep above code....

Comment: @balu Follow method-2 if you have not block file. you can use method-2 directly in your product view file. enable path hint and use this code where you want custom table data in phtml.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: yes , thank you very much...method 1 i followed, works fine.......

Comment: thanks man. saved me hours of searching :) method 1 works perfect on magento 2.1.8

Answer (score 2):

***In this case, you should create a custom model for this custom Table.***

Follow this https://www.softprodigy.com/store/article/create-model-and-collection-for-custom-table-in-magento2/ for reference.

In this  this you should declare  ***Model, Resource Model , Collection class***..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create block and template. And create a layout in to make a link between block.php and template.php.
then using $block object you can call block method.